# REST requests return 403 when running on EC2, but work on my own machine

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-403

I'm creating a simple application to collect data from a public API(stubhub) over time using Node.JS.

It collects data by making a request to the API endpoint using a Authorization: Bearer ~token~ header.

I'm making the request using "node-rest-client".

When I run this on my machine, everything works and I get my JSON data.

I created an Amazon EC2 instance, installed node, cloned my repository.

When i run this program on EC2, each HTTPS request returns a 403 forbidden error. Nothing has changed in the code. The only difference is that it's running on a different computer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

They could be blocking the Amazon IP block. I ran in to that issue recently. You could try a proxy.